# In which language did attributes first appear

Tags: c#, programming-languages, attributes, history

It seems that almost all features in C# were borrowed from another languages (OOP from Java, generics (parametric polymorphism) and lambdas from ML family, LINQ from Haskell's monads and dynamic from dynamic languages), but I don't know the origin of attributes(annotations in Java world). Is C# the first language that introduced attributes?

Comment: do you mean class atributtes ????

Comment: Attributes are not limited to C#

Comment: And I'm pretty sure the OOP was not borrowed from Java :p

Comment: Yes, class attributes and method attributes. Attributes also known as annotations in Java world.

Comment: @rystov wait, annotations are separate. Do you mean a (private) attribute/property of a class?

Comment: Java OOP was borrowed from C++, which borrowed it from Smalltalk. I thought C# generics were borrowed from Ada, though I'm not familiar enough with C# or ML to tell if your version is more accurate. If LINQ is based on Haskell monads (as opposed to just being a domain-specific sublanguage) I'll be extremely surprised - either way it's not particularly original. Genuinely original languages can probably be counted on your fingers - maybe even on just one hand. The rest is just evolution through minor tweaks and mix-and-match - a bit like a genetic algorithm.

Comment: @Steve314 yes, there are a lot of roots of those concepts, but I don't know any root of attributes, so it makes me think that it is a C# innovation.

Comment: @Steve314:  Actually, C++ took its OOP from Simula-67, as Stroustrup has pointed out in several places.  I've read that Java and C# are closer to Smalltalk, but I don't know Smalltalk well enough to comment.

Comment: @Steve314 Not the LINQ syntax, but the whole idea of different LINQ providers that stand between collection operations and real data is something close to monads. It's really fun to see the concept taken back to the start in F#, where LINQ is supported through so-called workflows, which are quite like monads—but, unlike in C#, F# workflows they are even more generic and don't limit themselves to LINQ.

Comment: @gaearon - that still sounds like any other abstraction layer to me, and pretty much what SQL is for at a different level. A monad is just an algebra. E.g. the Python list comprehensions - though they borrow from Haskell - aren't monadic. The underlying monadic structure isn't there, and you can't mix-and-match with e.g. a Haskell-like "do" notation or explicit bind operators. Python list comprehensions could easily have been copied directly from mathematical set notation, with no need for a monad connection. Could I make a similar argument against LINQ being monadic?

Comment: @Steve314: I only mean that different query providers define different ways to select, filter, aggregate as if these functions would intercept your code flow—this looks similar to monads to me. I write [where artist.Name == "Beatles"] knowing that Where might do something else with Name other than compare it (e.g. turn it into SQL). I'd say LINQ isn't monadic in implementation but it carried some design from monads. However, F# is much more monadic, and in F# LINQ is done *using* monads—see http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/10/13/functional-c-linq-as-a-monad.aspx

Comment: @gearon - SQL may do many things to handle your query. SQL is a standard language, not an implementation. Your database manager may optimise it (so that `Name == "Beatles"` becomes an index lookup rather than a comparison), or may send your query over a network to another database manager. Also, you haven't got my point that list comprehensions aren't the same as the monads that sometimes implement them (set comprehensions must surely predate monads in math?). All programming languages are implemented ultimately by translation to machine code - does that mean LINQ is close to machine code?

Comment: @gearon - in comparison, I have an incomplete DSL for tree data structures. It has a concept of summaries in nodes, a generalisation of key handling, which *is* reminiscent of monads - or better, the simpler monoids. An associative operator combines summaries from children to create a summary for the parent. At the leaf layer, there are "map" and "filter" functions (how to translate a single value into a single-item summary, and which values to include). It isn't just a reminder of something I once saw done with an algebra - it is modelled using key algebraic concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw attributes for the first time as method or parameter annotations in COM IDL (Interface Definition Language) files back in C++ world. I do not know if they were invented there or not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367042.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think it was UML with stereotypes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-Oriented_Programming

Comment: Yeah, I though about UML too.